# Piece of code that can kill computer performance

Tags: c#, performance

I'm searching for code in c# that can kill computer performance (CPU performance, maybe cpu - memory link performance too) as much as it is possible (it will run on 4 core box so I'm going to create 4 threads and run it simultaneously).

Should it work on int / double / numeric data type / should it have some crazy data structures (but it should not take too much memory) .

Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: `while(true){}` ?

Comment: @Klaus doesn't consume much memory :)

Comment: @Klaus - would also probably only occupy a single processor.

Comment: @marcog and it doesn't contact with memory too much ...

Comment: Don't forget that those 4 cores could potentially have hyper-threads that you might want to run threads on too.

Comment: Sometimes I have to test computers remotely and I want to check what happen which them, when they are heavily overwhelmed.

Comment: A [fork bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb).

Comment: Most OS'es will prevent this from occupying `all` of the process tables.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Calculate `PI` using all processors.

Comment: It worked on Star Trek, it can work for you.

Comment: @RQDQ - I must have missed that episode.

Comment: Probably this one: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H20cKjz-bjw

Answer (score 6):

You could use parallel Linq to generate a Mandelbrot ([Jon Skeet has the code readily available](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2007/10/03/linq-to-silliness-generating-a-mandelbrot-with-parallel-potential.aspx)).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to kill a machine's performance, try hitting the disk, because IO interrupts tend to affect everything even on a good CPU scheduler. Something like enumerating a directory of many little files, or writing a lot of big files to disk would do the trick.

Comment: Great idea enumerating like enumerating Windows directory, any more suggestion with HDD ?

Comment: You can combine any other suggestion here and just write the output to a file. Make sure you flush your buffers between every write so it actually goes to disk rather than just staying in memory.

Comment: There are some application that can kill system performance by disks IO you simply run it and everything stops, but I think that simple read write might have too low priority

Comment: +1 Great answer, people tend to forget this aspect when considering overall system performance.

Answer (score 4):

Have a program that writes copies of its executable to the drive multiple times for each thread.  Have each of these copies of the program then triggered by the program. :)

Comment: That's a different question altogether.  :P

Comment: It stops when the computer does :)

Comment: Searching for more controlled way :P

Comment: You could add code that counts existing instances of the program and throttles itself at some preset limit, I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

Why re-invent the wheel?  Use existing [Load Testing software](http://www.google.com/search?q=computer+load+test+software&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a).

Comment: No it must be a custom solution.

Comment: @Darqer- "It must be custom?" Why put that kind of constraint on solving the problem?  I thought you wanted to waste the computer's time, not yours.

Comment: I have to be able to control it (turn it on / off) through simple tcp / ip call :). Well and second it might be interesting to implement it on my own :) kind of programming fun :)

Answer (score 2):

Calculate a long sequence of prime numbers. The following link contains code that can be modified to do this..

[Program to find prime numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510124/program-to-find-prime-numbers)

Answer (score 2):

Call `Bitmap.GetPixel`, in a loop, in an image processing application.

Answer (score 2):

I would say: a naieve (brute force) travelling salesman implementation:

([from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)):

*The Travelling Salesman Problem (TSP) is an NP-hard problem in combinatorial optimization studied in operations research and theoretical computer science. Given a list of cities and their pairwise distances, the task is to find a shortest possible tour that visits each city exactly once.*

Answer (score 1):

Brute force solving of N Queens (see wikipedia) for for example 64 queens.

Because a simple loop like this can be optimized away (sometimes only after a few minutes already running):

```
while(true) {
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Declare `i` as volatile to prevent the optimization

Comment: @finnw: Even if i is a global field and i is volatile, it's still possible that the latest JVM (or a future JVM) detects that this piece of code is only run once and therefor i can be made a local variable and therefor the volatile nature becomes irrelevant.

Comment: this is a .NET question, but I think you are wrong about Java also, because the VM cannot know that another class will not be loaded later that will read `i` by reflection.

Answer (score 1):

You can, as well, resolve a very long encrypted message, encrypted by a key such as 2048 bits.
That's a killer.

Answer (score 1):

An open-source, multithreaded 3D modeling program rendering an extremely complex lighted scene will pound the strongest system into submission.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, how about some infinite recursion in the spirit of StackOverflow?

```
void deathToAllRobots(int someMeaninglessValue) {
    deathToAllRobots(someMeaninglessValue+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int *x;
while(1)
{
     x = new int[10];
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look much like C#

Comment: Compilers will probably optimise this one too.