# program that checks if any even number greater than 4 is a sum of two prime numbers

Tags: performance, primes

I have the following problem:
Given that the even numbers greater than 4 can be obtained by addition of 2 prime
numbers, I have to write an algorithm which check it. The algorithm should take less time that O(n^2).

For example there is a set of numbers from 6 to n. If we have the number 6 the answer is 6=3+3 and for  22=17+5 and so on.

My first idea:

```
S - set of n numbers
for i=1 to n {
  //removing odd numbers
   if (S[i]%2!=0)
      continue;

   result = false;
   for j=2 to S[i]-2{
       if (j.isPrime) // prime test can be done in O(log^2(n))
          if ((S[i]-j).isPrime)
               result = true;
               break;
          else
               continue;
   }

   if (result == false)
       break;
}
```

Since I use 2 for-loops, the total running time of this algorithm should be
`O(n*n)*O(log^2(n)) = O(n^2*log^2(n))` which is not less than `O(n^2)`.
Does anybody have an idea to reduce the running time to get the required time of less than `O(n^2)`?

Answer (score 2):

If set contains big numbers I've got nothing.

If max(S) < n ^ 2 / log(n) than:

You should preprocess which numbers from interval [1, max(S)] are primes.
For preprocessing you can use [sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Then, you are able to check if number is a prime in O(1) and complexity of your solution becomes O(N^2).

Comment: Your idea sounds good, but unfortunately I have to do it in LESS than O(n^2).

Comment: I just have idea. There are approx. n / lg (n) prime numbers that are <= n (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Number_of_prime_numbers_below_a_given_number). If you select random 10 * lg(n) prime numbers, than there is good chance that you select prime number X, that N - X is also a prime.

Answer (score 1):

This is [Goldbach's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture). Primality testing is known to be in **P** (polynomial time), but the break-even is ridiculously high - in practice, you will not be able to do this in anywhere near **O(n^2)**.

If we assume you only need to deal with relatively small numbers, and can precompute the primes up to a certain limit, you still need to find candidate pairs. The prime counting function gives approximately:
 `n / ln(n)` primes, less than `(n)`. Subtracting the candidate prime `(p)` from `(n)` gives an odd number `(q)`. If you can look up the primality of `(q)` with a complexity of: `n.ln(n)`, or better - i.e., an **O(1)** lookup table for *all* odd numbers less than the limit - you can achieve **O(n^2)** or better.

Answer (score 0):

You can run only until square root of N, this sufficient for determine if the number is prime or not.
this will reduce your running time.

also take a look at the following question - [Program to find prime numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510124/program-to-find-prime-numbers)