# How to use CheckIfPrime

Tags: vb.net

I need to use the `CheckIfPrime` item in my code, but having some issue, may i know how should I deal with it? Do I need to make declaration?

```
For number As Integer = 1 To 30
    If CheckIfPrime(number) = True Then
        sb.Append(number.ToString & " ")
    End If
Next
```

Please advice on how can I do that in Visual Basic.

Comment: Do you have a method CheckIfPrime(int n)?

Answer (score 2):

The `VB.net` has no `CheckIfPrime` method, so to deal with it in your task we need to create a method to check the number if is *prime* or *not.*

```
   Public Function CheckIfPrime(number As Integer) As Boolean
        For i As Integer = 2 To number - 1
            If number Mod i = 0 Then
                Return False
            End If
        Next
        Return True
    End Function
```

**Usage**

```
   For number As Integer = 1 To 30
      If CheckIfPrime(number) = True Then
       'Console.WriteLine(number.ToString & " ")
       sb.Append(number.ToString & " ")
      End If
   Next
```

[`Source`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10194599/1080742)