# function for testing whether the number is prime or not?

Tags: c#, c++, algorithm, primes

I needed a method to check whether given number is prime or not. I searched on internet and I found different functions but they were complex. So, I designed my own method for checking whether the number is prime or not. It is working for me. I just wanna know if it is correct or not. The code is given below:

```
bool IsPrime(int n)
{
    for (int i = 2; i <= 7; i++)
    {
        if (i < n && n % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (i == n)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why 7? Don't you need to test each value of `i` up to and including the square root of `n`?

Comment: call `IsPrime(121)` and see if you think it's right or not.

Comment: If you want to know whether it's correct, unit test it or prove it.

Comment: You'll want to test beyond 7. This will think 11 is not prime.

Comment: 121 is not a prime, but that function will return true.  It only checks for primes with a divisor between 2 and 7.  I think if you check for divisors between 2 and sqrt(n), it'll work, but very inefficiently.

Comment: 11 is prime, last statement will return true for 11 @MikeSeymour

Comment: also: test for i=2 before the loop, then do `for(int i=3; i < sqrtOfN; i+=2)`

Comment: The logic of your function says that a number is prime if it is not divisible by any number from 2 through 7. That's not the definition of prime. As others have said, 121 is not divisible by 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, or 7, yet is still not prime.

Comment: @ZohaibAslam: Sorry, I misread the final return. In that case, as others said, it'll think 11^2 (121) is not prime. Either way, you need to check at least all prime numbers up to `sqrt(N)`, not just up to 7.

Comment: thank you all of you :) i got the point. i posted this question because i wasn't sure about whether this will work correctly or not, and now i know it will not work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Program to find prime numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510124/program-to-find-prime-numbers)

Comment: Bit late to the game here, but see [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38985869/3504007) below for the "proper" way to check if any number is a prime - quickly, using Euler's Theorem.  I have simplified it into a copy paste method which you can recycle.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, it is not correct.

Kind answer: Here's working code:

```
bool IsPrime(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1) return false;      // .. , -1, 0, 1
    if (n == 2) return true;        // 2
    if (n % 2 == 0) return false;    // 4, 6, 8, ...
    int sqrt = (int)Math.Sqrt(n); // largest possible factor        
    for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt; i+=2)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Remark: There are **many** algorithm that work better, faster, etc...

---

**Edit**

Using @Blastfurnace's idea and some more here an optimized version:

```
bool IsPrime(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1) return false;      // .. , -1, 0, 1    
    if (n % 2 == 0) return (n==2);    // 2 and even numbers
    if (n % 3 == 0) return (n==3);    // 3 and divisible by 3
    if (n % 5 == 0) return (n==5);
    if (n % 7 == 0) return (n==7); // the magic 7 from OP 
    if (n < 11) return false;
    // calc sqrt as rare as possible, its expensive
    int sqrt = (int)Math.Sqrt(n); // largest possible factor  
    // skip 9, already done with n%3
    for (int i = 11; i <= sqrt; i+=2) if (n % i == 0) return false;

    return true;
}
```

This should save some CPU cycles.

Comment: And it does (incorrectly) think that 1 is. Both 1 and 2 will need special cases.

Comment: Another way to special case multiples of 2 is to say `if (n % 2 == 0) return (n == 2);`. Then you won't test odd numbers to see if they're equal to 2.

Comment: @Blastfurnance Well - this replaces a few cycles in the CPU with quite some cycles in my brain to understand my code... ;)

Answer (score 0):

From the definition of a prime number, "An integer greater than one is called a prime number if its only positive divisors (factors) are one and itself.", 0 and 1 are not prime numbers.

Correction of DrKoch's answer:

```
bool IsPrime(int n)
{
    if( n == 0 || n == 1)
       return false;
    else if(n == 2)
       return true;
    else if(n%2 == 0)
       return false;
    else {
       int sqrt = (int)Math.Sqrt(n);

       for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt; i+=2)
       {
           if (n % i == 0)
              return false;
       }

       return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for improving my code. Your implementation thinks -1 is a prime.

Comment: I am assuming no negative numbers are allowed.

Comment: You know: A good programmer looks in both directions before crossing a road - even a one-way road...

Comment: Please notice that the statement "return true;" in your edited answer is out the body of the function.