# Check prime numbers

Tags: c#, primes

I need to make a GUI application that checks prime numbers when the user input two numbers. The criteria is that I make two methods, one that checks **if a number is prime** and that is my `isPrime(int n)` and another that checks which of the two inputs is lower/higher so that the program knows where to start.

I can't manage to do this. When I run the script I don't have any output in Listbox.

My code so far:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num1, num2;
    num1 = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    num2 = Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text);

    for (int i = num1; i <= num2; i++) //Method that checks which of the two inputs is lower/hihger
    {
        if (isPrime(i))
        {
            for (int j = 2; j <= 1 / 2; j++)
            {
                if (i % j == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (i == 0 && i != 1)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(i);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static bool isPrime(int n) //Method to check prime numbers
{
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `j <= 1 / 2` ? Should that be `i / 2`? Also `i == 0 && i != 1` doesn't make any sense. Neither does the entire "method for checking which input is lower/higher."

Comment: Can you explain your "Method that checks which of the two inputs is lower/higher" loop? I'm not sure how it's supposed to work, or what it's intended to do with the one that it's identified as lower or higher.

Comment: Is the goal to put all of the prime numbers between num1 and num2 into a listbox?

Comment: @GuyIncognito Yes, sir! j <=i/2

Comment: @Rup Yes, sir! So when I run the GUI application I input two numbers and I need to get all prime numbers between them.

Comment: If you just need to swap num1 and num2 so that num1 <= num2 then you could e.g. `if (num1 > num2) { int temp = num1; num1 = num2; num2 = temp; }`

Comment: Could you, please, describe the *initial problem*? Given two numbers `num1` and `num2` you want to obtain a collection of what? Could you provide some *examples*? What is the desired result for, say, `num1 = 1, num2 = 10`?

Comment: Do you really want to _compute_ primes each time (and on the GUI Thread)? I'd pre-compute all primes in the int32 span of numbers and have them in some kind of list. Then you only need to query that list for the span of [Min(num1, num2), Max(num1, num2)].

Comment: @Rup So I created the method isPrime(int n) that check if the number is prime and I have to create the second method where I need loop from the lower number to the higher number and then call for method isPrime(i)... but I can't get output

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Desire result is to get all prime numbers between num1 and num2, that can be any number

Comment: You don't get output because `if (i == 0 && i != 1)` will never be true.

Comment: @Fidor I see that mistake, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `isPrime` function is correct, just minor change you need is that update condition to `i <= Math.Sqrt(n)` as `for (int i = 2; i <= Math.Sqrt(n); i++)`. That would be more `efficient`. [Sieve of Eristhostenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

You can also refer below links to find better and efficient way to check `isPrime`. As suggested by [@Fildor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/982149/fildor) in comments.

- [Program to find prime numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510124/program-to-find-prime-numbers)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1072205/982149

To find `min` or `max` value from two inputs use `Math.Min` & `Math.Max` like shown below. And update your `for` loop as below.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num1, num2;
    num1 = Math.Min(Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text), Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text));
    num2 = Math.Max(Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text), Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text));

    for (int i = num1; i <= num2; i++) //Method that checks which of the two inputs is lower/hihger
    {
        if (i != 0 && i != 1 && isPrime(i))
        {               
            listBox1.Items.Add(i);
        }
    }
}

private static bool isPrime(int n) //Method to check prime numbers
{
    for (int i = 2; i <= Math.Sqrt(n); i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You do realize that this is inefficient as hell, do you? (Given OP's implementation of `isPrime`)

Comment: @Fildor I can't see any other way of doing it... sorry

Comment: @Fildor feels free to suggest a better `isPrime` implementation

Comment: Do a search for "[Sieve of Eristhostenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)"

Comment: @bradbury9 I wouldn't at all. I'd have a precompiled set of primes to look up.

Comment: And you even can find some on here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1510186/982149 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/1072205/982149

Comment: @Fildor, Thanks man, One of the link I have already added. Also added another one as it would definitely help more.

Comment: @Karan Sorry for bothering you again, my method for checking prime numbers is not working when I put down Math.Sqrt(n), I mean if I check from 1 to 10 it's showing 2, 3, 4,5, 7, and 9... am I doing something wrong or what do I need to change there?

Comment: That was my bad. You should update condition in for loop as `i <= Math.Sqrt(n)`. Updated answer also.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start from `isPrime`. Since it takes `int n` as an argument, `n` can be up to `int.MaxValue ~ 2_000_000_000`;
*2 billions* iterations is a bit too many when we can easily implement a routine with `sqrt(2_000_000_000) / 2 ~ 30_000` loops only:

```
    private static bool isPrime(int n) {
      if (n <= 1)
        return false;
      else if (n % 2 == 0)
        return n == 2;

      int max = (int)(Math.Sqrt(n) + 0.5);

      for (int divisor = 3; divisor <= max; divisor += 2)
        if (n % divisor == 0)
          return false;

      return true;   
    }
```

Now, it's time to get the primes between `num1` and `num2`:

```
    for (int i = num1; i <= num2; ++i)
      if (isPrime(i))
        listBox1.Items.Add(i);
```

please, note, that since we've optimized `isPrime` we can keep `for` loop being very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another view to the problem:

I wouldn't check ( as in "compute" ) primes here *at all*.

Int32 contains a pretty finite number of primes, which allows us to either precompute or even just download a list from the internet if you can find one.

As soon as we have it, all you need to do is a lookup of those that happen to be in the desired range.