# Prime Numbers in Java (return next prime when false)

Tags: java, primes

```
public class PrimeNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 6;
        boolean isPrime = true;

        for (int i = 2; i <= num - i; i++) {
            if (num % i == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        int nextPrime = num++;
        {
            while (isPrime = false) {


            }
            if (isPrime)
                System.out.println("Is a prime number");
            else
                System.out.println("Is not a prime number" + "the next prime number is" + nextPrime(num));
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to code in Java in order to find the next prime number while the previously returned is false, but I am really confused about how to proceed with "while" code. This is what I have tried until now:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Program to find prime numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510124/program-to-find-prime-numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two functions: one (say, `isPrime`) to check if the number is prime or not and the second (say, `nextPrime`) to find the next prime. The logic in the second function will be quite straight forward: keep incrementing the number by `1` until `isPrime` returns `true`.

Note that you need to check only up to the square root of the number in order to determine if it is prime. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test to learn more about it.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        if (isPrime(n)) {
            System.out.println("It is a prime number");
        } else {
            System.out.println("It is not a prime number. The next prime number is " + nextPrime(n));
        }
    }

    static boolean isPrime(int n) {
        if (n == 1 || n == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    static int nextPrime(int n) {
        while (!isPrime(n)) {
            n++;
        }
        return n;
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter an integer: 10
It is not a prime number. The next prime number is 11
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter an integer: 11
It is a prime nmber
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I want to ask you a question regarding this code, as I am a beginner: regarding the nextPrime part, why do we code  n++;
        }
        return n;

Comment: @Maria - Programming is all about thinking as if you are doing Maths. Think about what you would do if you are given a number, `n` and asked to find the next prime number. You will first check if it is prime or not and if it turns out to be non-prime, you will try the next number (which `n++`). The operation, `n++` means `n = n + 1`. If the next number also turns out to be non-prime, you will increment it by `1` and repeat the process until you arrive at a prime number. Feel free to comment in case you have any further doubt.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find a prime number, you basically need a nested loop. So I'd recomend having your for loop INSIDE the while loop. OR you can have a do-while loop on the outside that keeps looping until you found a prime number.

Your code should look like this:

```js
public class PrimeNumbers {

    public static boolean check_prime(int num){
        
        for (int i = 2; i <= num-i ; i++) { 
            if (num % i == 0) {             
                return false;
            }
        } 
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int num = 6;

        boolean isPrime= true;

        if(!check_prime(6)){                        
            int nextPrime = num;
            do{
                nextPrime++;
                if (check_prime(nextPrime)) {             
                    isPrime = true;
                    break;
                 }else{
                    isPrime = false;
                 }
            }while(!isPrime);
        }
    
        if (isPrime)
            System.out.println("Is a prime number");
        else
            System.out.println("Is not a prime number" +"the next prime number is" + nextPrime);
    }}}
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks a lot! What I am trying to define is another variable that tells me what the next prime number is after asking the program whether a number is prime or not. So the code should be: ask whether a given number is prime or not. In case yes, print. In case no, print no and indicate the next prime number. I am having trouble to define the variable of the next prime number.

Comment: Okay I see, I have edited my code above, hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 0):

How about this snippet?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number= 14; // will print the second SOUT statement with 17
    if (isPrime(number)) {
        System.out.println(number+ " is a prime number");
    } else {
        System.out.println(number+ " is not a prime number, " + 
                "the next prime number is " + nextPrime(number));
    }
}
```

```
/**
 *  Check if the number is a prime number
 *  For 0 or 1 you can return false, for the rest if is divisible by each number
 *  You might want to throw an exception for the negative input 
 */
static boolean isPrime(int number) {
    if (number==0 || number==1) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i=2; i<=number/2; i++) {
        if (number%i==0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

```
/**
 *  Iterate the number by one until you find a prime number using the while cycle
 */
static int nextPrime(int number) {
    int prime;
    while (true) {
        boolean isPrime = isPrime(++number);
        if (isPrime) {
            prime = number;
            break;
        }
    }
    return prime;
}
```